# Fill column with counting value every n row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 10-minute time series data, I want to create a column that counts the number 2-hour periods, by column group.

So, for the first 12 rows, the value will be 1, then for the next 12 rows it will be 2, etc.
But do this to column groups.

dataframe with desired outcome

```
df
timestamp            uid     col1      new   
2020-10-10 00:00     1        10        1
2020-10-10 00:00     2        20        1
2020-10-10 00:10     1        5         1
...
2020-10-10 01:50     2        10        1
2020-10-10 02:00     1        30        2
2020-10-10 02:00     2        50        2 
....
```

Comment: Can't you just derive this from the timestamp?  Take "hour / 2 + 1"?

Comment: I suppose that works! How would this work if I want to count the 2-day periods, instead of 2 hour? Just looking for other possibilities for solution. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Again, you should be able to extract that from the timestamp.  Compute the delta between the timestamp in row i and the timestamp in row 0 in days.  pandas has functions to do that kind of thing.